# Make water droplets charged?

Tags: electrostatics, water, charge

Normally water molecules are electrically neutral.
But I have seen somewhere ideas about electric energy generators mentioning that water droplets might be used in some applications as they are charged particles.

Is it really so?

I know that water droplets [get charged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect) due to friction in the bottoms of waterfalls producing static discharges. But is there some other more fundamental process which makes evaporated or sprayed water droplets become charged?

Comment: clouds? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning

Comment: I believe that the charge of clouds is also explained by triboelectric effect. I've found a video where the general description of the process is given: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqksCHWROBU It is clear that they are referring to some different way of obtaining charged water droplets. Sounds like just evaporating the water makes it ionized.

Comment: http://www.hk-phy.org/iq/kelvin_generator/kelvin_generator_e.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that evaporative ionization is the *opposite* effect of what you're looking for, per the [general discussion on ion processes in evaporated droplets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrospray_ionization#Ionization_mechanism).

This constrains the range of charge-transfer in droplets to the triboelectric effect, as you mentioned.

The Kelvin Generator, including discussion about [charge formation that exceed models](http://www.linux-host.org/energy/akelv1.html), may be more than triboelectric, due to ground effects - which is to say that charge may come from other sources that *the system of droplet and atmosphere*.  The only way I could see a Kelvin Generator involve Electrospray Ionization is through corrosion or dissolving of the conductive cups that collect the water.

The AmSci group suggests that [the charge arrives from slowing the water droplets' fall](http://amasci.com/emotor/ikelv.html).  Their model could align with the idea that ion-transfer from droplet to system occurs via [Coulomb Fission.](http://addis.caltech.edu/research/GuW_2007.pdf)

Comment: + I think your mention of the [*Kelvin water dropper*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin_water_dropper) is right on target.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey The Kelvin demo is good, but the underlying model is yet unclear.  Coulomb Fission could lead to ion-transfer, but it may not be enough to speak to the [streak-photos showing droplets flying upwards, in a field-pattern](http://img.youtube.com/vi/aNE-3EBLmA8/0.jpg).  This effect is important in the answer.